# Какой из способой создания объектов в js считается наиболее лучшим?

Tags: javascript

Как лучше создавать объекты при помощи **new** или **create**?
И есть ли реальная разница между этими способами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница существенная, это вообще разные не взаимозаменяемые способы.

1. new создает экземпляр объекта, а Object.create() создает наследника прототипа.
2. new запускает конструктор, а Object.create() - нет.

```
var Common = function (arg) {

    console.log(this.property, arg);
};

Common.prototype.property = "Hello world";

var obj1 = new Common("!"); //правильно

var obj2 = Object.create(Common); //неправильно
//-------------------------------- использование Object.create()
var UnCommon = function (arg) {
    console.warn(arg);
    this.ParentConstructor.call(this, arg);
}

UnCommon.prototype = Object.create(Common.prototype);
UnCommon.prototype.ParentConstructor = UnCommon.prototype.constructor; // это надо, если 
UnCommon.prototype.constructor = UnCommon; // хочется наследовать и UnCommon тоже

var obj3 = new UnCommon('?');

//----------------------------

// дурацкий способ использования Object.create() как new:

obj4 = Object.create(UnCommon.prototype);
UnCommon.call(obj4, "@");

//----------------------

console.log(obj1, obj2, obj3,obj4);
console.log(obj1.property, obj2.property, obj3.property,obj4.property);
```

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо! Не могу сказать, что полностью понимаю... У меня с прототипами беда, когда я читаю я полностью понимаю, но как только отвернусь от монитора, то чувство, что вся информация стерается :) Наверное, нужно что-то поделать с ними, чтобы в кору прям въелось..

Comment: попробуйте ES5.1 спеку почитать, там точно написано что должно быть.

http://es5.javascript.ru/

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо!Перевод отправляется в закладки :)