# Достаточно ли передать контекст для наследования в js?

Tags: javascript

Уже спрашивал [нечто подобное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/350737/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-js-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC), но до конца не уяснил. По этому, лучше переспросить - достаточно ли этого будет для наследования или нужно связывать протопипы?

```
var SuperClass = function(name){
    this.name = name;
};

var ChildClass = function(name, age){
    SuperClass.call(this, name);

    this.age = age;
};

var childClass = new ChildClass('CHILD', 100);
console.log(childClass.name, childClass.age); // 'CHILD', 100
```

**Добавлено:**

```
Кажется понял -

var SuperClass = function(name){
    this.name = name;
};

SuperClass.prototype.children = function(){
    return 'default';
};

var ChildClass = function(name, age){
    SuperClass.call(this, name);

    this.age = age;
};

ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);

var childClass = new ChildClass('CHILD', 100);
console.log(childClass.name, childClass.age, childClass.children()); // 'CHILD', 100, 'default'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну если вы наследуете только конструктор, то да - хватит и такого.

но по идее, вы "не заботитесь" о том что в родительском прототипе и поэтому если родительский прототип будет иметь в конструкторе что-то вроде

```
function Super(name) {
    this.name=name;
    this.addNamePrefix();
}
//и собственные свойства/методы
Super.prototype.prefix="Super";
Super.prototype.addNamePrefix() {
    this.name=this.prefix+'_'+this.name;
}
```

то у вас в Child будет неожиданный результат.

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо! Не подумал об этом. Js вроде очень простой, но порой меня сильно запутывает.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите чтобы `ChildClass` наследовал и был наследником `SuperClass`, то нужно наследовать прототип:

```
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);
ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass

// и тогда
console.log(new ChildClass() instanceof SuperClass); // true
console.log(new ChildClass() instanceof ChildClass); // true
```

Comment: @RubaXa, вторая строчка нужна для того, чтобы не писать  
SuperClass.call(this, name); ?

Comment: `SuperClass.call(this, name);` — это просто выполнить метод в произвольном контексте, таким образом, в данном случае, мы получаем вызов родительского конструктора. Вторая строчка нужна, чтобы вернуть правильный конструктор, т.к. после `Object.create` он будет ссылаться на SuperClass.

Comment: Спасибо! И ещё вопрос - чтобы переопределить метод супер-класса нужно написать  
ChildClass.prototype.methodSuperClass = function(){}...   
Так нужно?

Comment: Да, всё верно:

    ChildClass.prototype.methodSuperClass = function (foo, bar) {
        SuperClass.prototype.methodSuperClass.call(this, foo, bar); // вызываем родительский метод, если нужно
        // ...
    };

Comment: вот интересно, а есть какой-нибудь шаблон, чтобы развернуть рекурсивный вызов всех конструкторов предков в цикл ?

Comment: Использовать:

 1. Минимальную обертку, а-ля `var ChildClass = SuperClass.extend({ .. });`
 2. ES6 + es6-transpiler (уже пора)

Comment: так  super(name); никуда рекурсию не денет. я вот про что - собираем все конструкторы предков в массив pre и делаем им 
    
    var t=this,a=[].splice.call(arguments);
    pre.forEach(function(p) {
         p.contructor.apply(t,a);      
    }

несколько проблем в реализации вижу 

   * надо сообщать конструктору предка, что он вызван потомком (можно последним аргументом решить)
   * надо как-то собрать предком (итерация по `__proto__`, но это не кошерно)

зачем нужно - для глубокого наследования.

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы хотите добиться и какую проблему решаете. У одного класса, может быть только один родитель. В ES6 (или при использовании «примитивной обертки») например, если не переопределять  конструктор, то он автоматом наследуется от родителя.

Comment: родитель один а предков - множество